Bottom sheet background zoom effect flutter
i find similar question asked on reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/xwvnxg/how_to_achieve_this_bottom_sheet_background_zoom/
how can we achieve similar effect on flutter?

This package might help you to achieve it: https://pub.dev/packages/sheet
Edit: This package can do the same and has more popularity
https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet

i was looking for one, this is exactly what i need thanks

you can look at this package, it seems they are similar
https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
